# Java Socket OutputStream write one byte[] as two separate messages

Tags: java, sockets

Trying to send a byte[] through TCP Socket in Java, it sends a specific array as two separate messages, while other arrays are sending as one message.
In more details, I convert a hex String to a byte[] using the following function:

```java
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            b[i] = (byte) v;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

And then I send it through Java TCP Socket:

```java
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3030);
Socket socket = server.accept();
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
// sample hex string
String msg = "F0700F8000F42400001544952414E00000000000000000000000662000E00060000";
out.write(HexUtiles.hexStringToByteArray(msg));
```

In debugging the code I found out it separate the array in byte number 1024. Also, increasing and decreasing the socket buffer size made no differences.

In addition, there is no 0A (Hex String of `\n`) in the message! I guess there is some strange behavior in the `write` method that sends a byte[] array as two messages! How can I send the byte[] as only one message?

Comment: How are you reading those arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "messages" in TCP. Everything is sent as a stream and it's undefined how it will be chunked on the other end. Chunks might be split or joined together.

Send the byte size before each array using `DataOutputStream`. Read the size on the other end using `DataInputStream` and then that many bytes. This way you will be able to recreate your arrays at the other end.

Another option is to use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` and send the arrays as objects.

Comment: Could you tell me what could be the reason that the 'write' method split speefic byte array in two?

Comment: Those arrays might be too big to fit in single network packet or OS might decide to send or receive them in smaller chunks for performance reasons.

Comment: The size of the array is just 1700 and since this happen only for specefic array, maybe it's related to the data of array.

Comment: [1700 bytes will almost always be fragmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit). It might be combined into a single read, depending on how fast you read it and how fast both packets are delivered.